# Segmentation fault for malloc function of a 2D char array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management

Here is my code snippet to create the 2D array that holds char array. It would be great if someone could find out what could be the reason. I have tried using both `malloc()` and `calloc()` to allocate memory to the 2D array, yet no positive signs.

Code Snippet:

```
char** attrNames = (char **)malloc(3*sizeof(char*))
for (m = 0; m < 3; m++) {
        attrNames[m] = (char *)malloc(2 * sizeof(char*));
        strcpy(schema->attrNames[m], temp_buff2[m]);
    }
```

I am trying to allocate the memory and then going on a loop and again allocating memory and copy the data from a variable called `temp_buff2` (has character data) into the char array.

Comment: Exactly. `(char *)malloc(2 * sizeof(char*))` allocates space for two pointers, not for anything they point to.

Comment: You can also allocates as: `char** attrNames = malloc (3* sizeof *attrNames);` . Using `sizeof` with the pointer you are allocating helps prevent inadvertent `sizeof (type)` mismatches. Similarly `attrNames[m] = malloc (2 * sizeof **attrNames);` (adjusted to include the `strlen` to get the correct count as above)

Comment: I do not know why, but none of them are working

Comment: Can I just do strcpy without allocating the memory?

Comment: Schema is a struct that contains few integer members , few char array and a 2D char array which is what I'm trying to initialise

Comment: Is it really a 2D array of char (all rows the same length) or is it an array of cstrings?

Comment: Best way to learn would be to print the call stack and examine the arguments to strcpy

Comment: It is usually a single character, that needs to be stored in the 2D array.Since i cannot change the struct, Ive to store the string of length one as char array in the 2D array.

Comment: Why do you copy the string to `schema->attrNames[m]` instead of `attrnames[m]`? `schema->attrnames[m]` may be uninitialized?

Comment: @MikeCAT: I need to store the value in the struct schema - hence have to store. Looks like the error is elsewhere, not matter what Its throwing me segmentation fault

Comment: The references to "attrNames[m]" vs "schema->attrNames[m]" are troubling, as MikeCat pointed out -- there is some sort of discontinuity there.  Furthermore, let's focus on: "attrNames[m] = (char *)malloc(2 * sizeof(char*));".  Assuming you're compiling 32-bit, you're giving attrNames[m] 8 bytes of storage (2 * 4).  Is that what you intended to do?  Does "temp_buff2[m]" point to a null-terminated string, which strcpy() can then copy into the storage (because that is what it is going to try to do).

Comment: @Brinda MikeCAT's question was valid about schema vs attrnames and so was your answer.  What's missing here is the setup code for the schema variable as well as the corresponding struct definition.  You could easily be overruning the struct and corrupting something else which come back to bite you later.  You mentioned segfault.  Do you know the line of code that causes it (e.g. run under gdb)?

Comment: @CraigEstey :You are right - While i debugged, the data in temp_buff2 is all fine until i do the malloc for 2D char array. Any inputs? I'm guessing because of this malloc, all the data is getting corrupted and i'm unable to proceed further.

Comment: @Brinda I think most of the commenters, in addition to analysis are implying that you need to post [more of] your code.  I'd edit your question and add all of it in a separate code block at the bottom.  The root cause of the bug could be anywhere.  Right now, I can't tell if the struct definition needs a fix, the mallocs are insufficient, or the copy operations are too long/short.  If you do, send me a comment, and I'd be glad to look at it further.

Comment: Here is my struture definition:
typedef struct Schema
    {
      int numAttr;
      char **attrNames;
      DataType *dataTypes;
      int *typeLength;
      int *keyAttrs;
      int keySize;
    } Schema;

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. Even though memory allocation error in your project might be unlikely, now is a good time to develop a good error handling reflex - it will save your bacon when you move on to more serious projects.

Note that char* pointer needs a buffer that is equal to the length of the string plus one extra byte. sizeof(char*) is a small value, only 8 on a 64-bit architecture - it just stores the value of the memory address where the string starts. Note that we need +1 on top of strlen() because strcpy() will store one extra byte (\0) as a string terminator.

```
char** attrNames = (char **)malloc(3*sizeof(char*));

if (!attrName)
{
  // handle memory error
}

for (m = 0; m < 3; m++) {
        attrNames[m] = (char *)malloc(strlen(temp_buff2[m])+1);
        if (!attrNames[m]) 
        {
           // handle memory error
        }

        strcpy(schema->attrNames[m], temp_buff2[m]);
    }
```

Memory error can be handled by returning an error code from your function or via a fatal exit like this:

```
fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
exit(1);
```

You will need to `#include <stdlib.h>` for the prototype of exit().

Answer (score 0):

You need to reserve enough space for whatever you have inside "temp_buff2". For example:

```
char** attrNames = (char **)malloc(3*sizeof(char*))
for (m = 0; m < 3; m++) {
    attrNames[m] = (char *)malloc( strlen(temp_buff2[m]) + 1 );
    strcpy(schema->attrNames[m], temp_buff2[m]);
}
```

Notice that I am adding 1 to the strlen result, this is because we need to reserve an additional byte for the null char terminator.